# Confidence interval for mean of lognormal distributed data

Tags: statistics, logarithms, confidence-interval

I have a variable X that is distributed log-normally.

I let Y = lnX ~ N($\mu$, $\sigma^2$) and I've been given that $\sigma$=0.3, $\bar{y}$ = 0.12 and n = 40.

So I find a confidence interval for the mean of the log-transformed data like this:

$(\bar{y}-z_{1-\alpha/2}\times\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}, \bar{y}+z_{1-\alpha/2}\times\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n})\\
(0.12-1.96\times\frac{0.3}{\sqrt 40}, 0.12+1.96\times\frac{0.3}{\sqrt 40})\\
(0.027, 0.213)$

To get the 95% confidence interval for E(X) (the original variable) I just raise e to the power of the endpoints of the interval I just calculated.

so the interval would be 
$(e^{0.027}, e^{0.213})=\\$
$(1.03, 1.24)$

Is this correct?

Thanks any help appreciated

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: The problem is that $E(X)$ is not $e^{\mu}$. In fact for a log-normal, $e^{\mu}$ is the median. See https://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n1/olsson.html and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33382/how-do-i-calculate-a-confidence-interval-for-the-mean-of-a-log-normal-data-set

Comment: @Kane: The mean of lognormal is $\exp(\mu + (1/2) \sigma ^2)$. Your confidence interval before exponentiation is only for $\mu$. You should take a serious look at the links.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer I actually used those links to create my answer. I know that the mean of lognormal is $e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}}$. I guess i don't understand how that changes the answer

Comment: @Kane: There are 2 issues. The bigger issue is what I mention in the comment above that mean of lognormal is not exponentiated mean of the corresponding normal. The other smaller issue is the preservation under exponentiating the confidence interval of the log transformed variables.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer should the lower limit of the interval be $e^{0.0027 + \frac{1}{2}0.36}$?

Comment: Your confidence interval is $0.027 \leq \mu \leq 0.213$. Assuming exponentiation preserves things (it actually doesnt) $e^{0.027} \leq e^{\mu} \leq e^{0.213}$. Now you (kind of) have a confidence interval for $e^{\mu}$. But you said you want a confidence interval for $E(X)$.

Comment: Why $(1/2)0.36$?

Comment: @Just_to_Answer if I'm following you correctly, you are saying that my calculation finds an interval for $e^{\mu}$ but what I really want is an interval for $e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}}$. So instead of $e^{0.027}$ (which is $e^{\mu}$) then I would go $e^{0.027 + \frac{1}{2}0.3^{2}}$ (which is $e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}}$) (sorry I was using $0.6^{2}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting https://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n1/olsson.html using $\theta=EX$

> It would seem natural to use the following "naïve" approach for
>   calculating a confidence interval for $\theta$. A confidence interval
>   for $\mu$ is calculated using standard methods. The limits of the
>   confidence interval are back-transformed to give the limits in a
>   confidence interval for $\theta$. [...an example illustrated...] This illustrates the fact that the naïve method gives a biased estimator of $\theta$

The method outlined by OP is this biased method.

The paper offers a few alternatives including Cox Method. If, as in OP's case $\sigma^2$ is known, a modification should be made to the Cox method. This modification would be to add $(1/2)\sigma^2$ to both ends of the confidence interval for $\mu$ and then take anti-log's.

The end of the paper also provides simulation studies to assess the coverage of the confidence intervals under each method.

Answer (score 0):

Quantiles and percentiles are preserved under increasing transformations like $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ so the 5th and 95th percentile of $X$ will still be the 5th and 95th percentile when transformed through $\exp$. (the preservation property is mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile)).

Comment: But unfortunately, $E(X)$ is not $e^{\mu}$. Please see https://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n1/olsson.html

Comment: To be emphatic, regardless of the exp/ln functions preserve percentiles or not - the confidence interval before exponentiation is a confidence interval for $\mu$. The mean of lognormal is $\exp(\mu + (1/2) \sigma ^2)$. NOT $\exp(\mu)$. So this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer could you please reply to my question showing helping me to understand where my understanding is incorrect?

Comment: @Just_to_Answer you're quite right, this does not answer OP's actual question at all. I accidentally mistook the question as one about percentiles of lognormal variables. And agreed, the mean is not a percentile (unlike the median) and is therefore not preserved, preventing the application of the above principle.