# Confidence Interval for $\operatorname{E}(X)$ when we know $\ln X$ has a normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

How can we calculate a confidence interval for $\operatorname{E}(X)$ when $\ln X$ has a normal distribution?(unknown parameters)

I was thinking of using the fact that $\dfrac{\widehat {\operatorname{E}}(\ln X) - \operatorname{E}(\ln(X))}{\operatorname{se} \left(\widehat{\operatorname{E}}(\ln X) \right)}$ having a t-distribution. But by Jensen's inequality, I cannot simply do $e^{E(\ln(X))}=E(X)$...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should have a look at the Galton's distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation_of_parameters

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285040/confidence-interval-for-mean-of-lognormal-distributed-data

Comment: @Just_to_Answer It's not the same situation since in that question the parameters are known. In mine they are unknown.

Comment: @an-old-man-in-the-sea Sure, I should've said "related". My goal was to link the other question. The JSE paper referenced there (https://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/v13n1/olsson.html) does deal with the scenario when the mean and variance of $\ln X$ are unknown.

Comment: @Just_to_Answer Thanks for the link ;)